# DataGridViewImageCell not showing image

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created an `DataGridViewImage` column for my `DataGridView`.

```
DataGridViewImageColumn guardar = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
{
    guardar.HeaderText = "";
    guardar.Name = "guardar";
    guardar.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
    guardar.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewImageCell();
    guardar.Image = Properties.Resources.empty_grilla;
    guardar.ToolTipText = "Guardar";
}
dgv_Bancos.Columns.Add(guardar);
```

The problem is that when I want to change the Image of an specific cell, it just does not changes.

This is my code, please help, I don´t know what is wrong

```
DataGridViewImageCell cell = (DataGridViewImageCell)dgv_Bancos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["guardar"];
cell.Value = Properties.Resources.guardar_grilla;
```

**RESOLVED!**

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this instead of using the `DataGridViewImageCell cell`

```
dataGridView1["guardar", e.RowIndex].Value = Properties.Resources.guardar_grilla;
```

Comment: Dumb error, I was not showing the column ¬¬. I didnt noticed because the former image is a blank one.. and has no header text.

Comment: you can use my answer anyway `:D`